# Difference between 'Metadata links' and 'Data links' field GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, metadata, getcapabilities, ows, link

What is the difference between the fields 'Metadata links' and 'Data links' in GeoServer? What is expected as input for the latter? (GeoServer  2.11.5)

Comment: This isn't specific to geoserver, this is defined by OGC service interface standards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Metadata links](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#basic-info)
>   Allows linking to external documents that describe the data layer. Currently only two standard format types are valid: TC211 and FGDC. TC211 refers to the metadata structure established by the ISO Technical Committee for Geographic Information/Geomatics (ISO/TC 211) while FGDC refers to those set out by the Federal Geographic Data Committee (FGDC) of the United States.

Data links are for similar information that doesn't fit those types. In fact you can put almost anything you like in there. Or, just ignore them too.